# On the contact us page of Stack Overflow Careers, the words "Select one" are not localized

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

Go to the Stack Overflow Careers [contact us](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/products/contact) page, scroll down to the bottom and select either French or German.

The words "Select one" in the dropdown menu in the middle of the page remain in English. The other menu items are OK though.

[image: Select one]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translations have been added and the text is now showing in the correct language(s).

Thank you for your report!